# python dictionary list, getting an item inside a bracket

Tags: python, dictionary

```
items = {
    'flour': [20, 10, 15, 8, 32, 15], 
    'beef': [3,4,2,8,2,4],
    'bread': [2, 3, 3],
    'cc': [0.3, 0.5, 0.8, 0.3, 1]
}
```

I ned to get the third element on each of the ingredients' bracket,
the answer will be (15, 2, 3, 0.8)

Please, thanks for your help!

Comment: It looks like you would find a good python tutorial on list and dictionaries helpful. There are many of these available online.

Answer (score 1):

You can do :

```
op = [v[2] for v in items.values()]

print(op)
```

Note: It won't maintain the same order in prior versions of python3.7

Comment: Worth noting that before python 3.7, you might not get the same order